# Scale an image added to canvas

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I am trying to create an image from an svg.

What I have done so far is to capture the inline svg created using RaphaelJS, I then create an image using the svg code and then I'm adding it to a canvas I found a post on here that showed me how to scale the image to fit the canvas.

However, I would like to make the image larger. I am fairly new to svg and canvas so I'm unsure if this is a good approach. My end goal is to generate and image that I can add to a pdf. The code I have used is below.

```
var svgc = document.getElementById('graph').innerHTML;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgc);
var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport');

context = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawImageScaled(image, context);

function drawImageScaled(img, ctx) {
    var canvas = ctx.canvas;
    var hRatio = canvas.width / img.width;
    var vRatio = canvas.height / img.height;
    var ratio = Math.min(hRatio, vRatio);
    var centerShift_x = (canvas.width - img.width * ratio) / 2;
    var centerShift_y = (canvas.height - img.height * ratio) / 2;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height,
                  centerShift_x, centerShift_y, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
}
```

I need to resize the canvas because the image generated is far too small.

I think I need to resize the image though but I'm not sure how. Thank you for any help.

Ive included the svg created by raphaeljs below.

```
<svg height="500" version="1.1" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; left: -0.5px;">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc>
    <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
    <rect x="200" y="20" width="50" height="460" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    <rect x="200" y="20" width="50" height="50" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffff00" stroke="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.5;" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M300,20L700,20" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
    <text x="350" y="30" text-anchor="middle" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Sample Info</tspan></text>
    <rect x="200" y="20" width="20" height="50" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#00cc00" stroke="#000000" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
    <rect x="200" y="70" width="50" height="100" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M300,70L700,70" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
    <text x="350" y="80" text-anchor="middle" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Sample Info</tspan></text>
    <rect x="200" y="170" width="50" height="300" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#0033cc" stroke="#000000" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.5;"></rect>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M300,170L700,170" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
    <text x="350" y="180" text-anchor="middle" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;"><tspan dy="3.5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Sample Info</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="480" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">0</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="434" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">50</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="388" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">100</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="342" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">150</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="296" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">200</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="250" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">250</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="204" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">300</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="158" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">350</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="112" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">400</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="66" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">450</tspan></text>
    <text x="195" y="20" text-anchor="end" font-family="&quot;Arial&quot;" font-size="10px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: end; font-family: 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; line-height: normal;" font="11px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif"><tspan dy="4" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">500</tspan></text>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M200.5,480L200.5,20M196,480.5L201,480.5M196,434.5L201,434.5M196,388.5L201,388.5M196,342.5L201,342.5M196,296.5L201,296.5M196,250.5L201,250.5M196,204.5L201,204.5M196,158.5L201,158.5M196,112.5L201,112.5M196,66.5L201,66.5M196,20.5L201,20.5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path>
    <rect x="100" y="20" width="15" height="460" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    <rect x="85" y="250" width="15" height="230" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    <rect x="115" y="250" width="15" height="230" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    </svg>
```

The issue was i was not setting the canvas height and width by setting the canvas width and height to the same as the svg it has corrected the image size.

Comment: can you please provide the `<svg>` tag, your code is fine with an external svg image

Comment: @PavelGatnar I've added the svg to my question, sadly because i am using raphael the svg is not an external image.

Comment: what is your canvas size?

Comment: I was not setting the height and width of the canvas i had not realized until you mentioned it, i wrongly presumed it would adjust to the image size. I've set the canvas height and width to the same as the svg and it works perfectly now. Thank you for your help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define the `width` and `height` of the svg image explicitly.
e.g.

```
<svg height="150" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect width="150" height="150" fill="green" stroke-width="10" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/372gtsw9/