# Fix max size to base64 png file generated from svg + html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg, png

Here is the problem,

I work on a svg editor where user can work on svg files that have "unlimited" sizes or so... But at some time, I need to convert the svg file to a png image.

Problem is that with big sizes, the png file becomes far too big. (>2Mo is already too big)

I need, somewhere, to set a maximum size to my png file. This file will only be used to print image on a a3 page or a4, so I don't really need BIG resolutions.

Here is how I actually proceed to get a png file from the svg :

**1. Code to build my png file :**

```
    /*
    svgContents -> is the whole svg code
    name -> is the name of the output file
    w -> the width i get from the svg container tag
    h -> the height i get from the svg container tag
    callback... (returns my conversion result, the file url)
    */
    function buildPngFile(svgContents,name,w,h,callback){

        var contents = svgContents;
        var fname = name;
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        myCanvas.setAttribute("width",w);
        myCanvas.setAttribute("height",h);
        var myCtxt = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        myCtxt.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
        myCtxt.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
        drawInlineSVG(myCtxt,contents,function(){
            $.ajax({ 
                type : 'POST',
                cache : false,
                url : './createPngFile.php',
                data : {'dataPng':myCanvas.toDataURL(),'map':map},
                dataType : 'json',
                error : function(response){
                    console.log("ERROR : "+response+"responsetext : "+response.responseText+"json : "+JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                success : function(response){
                    callback(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I thought that setting manually, in the code above, the width & height of my Canvas would solve the problem, but NOT AT ALL. If i fix it (for example to 1280/720) it only shows the part of the svg image corresponding to these values. So I only get a part of my svg on the png file. This does not work.

**2. drawInlineSvg function**

```
function drawInlineSVG(ctx, rawSVG, callback) {
    var svg = new Blob([rawSVG], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),
        domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
        url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),
        img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);     
        domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        callback(this);
    }
    img.src = url;
}
```

This just draws the svg into the canvas...

**3. createPngFile.php**

```
    $name = $_POST['map'];
    $data = $_POST['dataPng'];
    $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
    $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
    $file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/png/'.$name.'.png','w');
    fwrite($file,base64_decode($data));
    fclose($file);
    echo json_encode($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/png/'.$name.".png");
```

This returns the url to the png file. All this code is working fine, what I need is to limit my png pics sizes to a defined max-width or max-height to avoid getting huge .png files reaching more than 2Mo (for example)

Thanks for reading/help :)

Comment: what does `drawInlineSVG` do?

Comment: ooops :P let me edit my post

Answer (score 0):

you need to supply additional parameters in the call `ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);`

reuse the logic in `drawImageScaled` function from [Scale an image added to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774419/scale-an-image-added-to-canvas/29791795#29791795) to scale the image